# Parse logical JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, logic

I wonder if there exists some library to parse a JSON that contains logical operators to transform it into a flat query string.

Let's say as input I get:

```
{
    "Children":[
       {
          "ID":1,
       },
       {
          "ID":2,
       },
       {
          "Children":[
             {
                "ID":3,
             },
             {
                "ID":4,
             }
          ],
          "Type":"Or"
       }
    ],
    "Type":"And"
 }
```

And I want to convert it into simply:

```
(3 Or 4) AND 1 And 2
```

How would you do this in Python?

Comment: How did the all caps AND get in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your precise expectations are; in particular, this problem is a lot easier if you're OK with redundant parentheses.

Here's a simple recursive function with inadequate error checking (i.e. it's likely to raise an exception if the JSON doesn't precisely conform to expectations):

```py
def json_to_formula(j):
    if 'Children' in j:                                                                
        return '(' + f" {j['Type']} ".join(map(json_to_formula,
                                           j['Children'])) + ')'
    else:
        return str(j['ID'])
```

Comment: Thx, but what is f in the statement?

Comment: @hanshupe: A copy and paste error. Sorry. At the last minute, I thought that `f` wasn't a very good name for the function, but I copied the old function body instead of the fixed one.

Comment: there still one f :)

Comment: @HansHupe: `f"..."`  is a Python 3 formatted string literal ("f-string")

Comment: @HansHupe: Cool. But remember that it is only a rough guide :-). You'll need to adapt it as you add operator types. (For example, using `join` works fine for operators like `And` and `Or`, but it's not correct for unary operators like `Not`.)

Comment: yes, for my case it works, i am impressed by the size of the code, it took me much more to approach the problem